# how to disable MSI on tg3 driver?

Tags: linux, latency, broadcom

got some new HP DL380p G8 for Centos.
What's the correct options to disable MSI for the onboard Broadcom NICs?

I tried disable_msi in modprobe.conf.local and it doesn't work.

Thanks
Will

Comment: what version of centos?

Comment: Have you read this; http://www.parisc-linux.org/~willy/MSI-HOWTO.txt - bear in mind you probably actually have MSI-X rather than plain MSI

Comment: CentOS 6.4
Thanks for the URL

Comment: I wonder if I have to do the same thing to tg3 as bnx2.
"Configuring IRQ SMP affinity has no effect on some devices that use MSI with no MSI per-vector masking capability. Examples of such devices include Broadcom NetXtreme Ethernet devices that use the bnx2 driver."

Comment: Don't know sorry, can't pretend that I'm not interested in why you want to do this by the way

Comment: on some older cisco servers, we had bnx2 drivers on the onboard cards.  Try to lower the number of interrupts we would deal with. Pin down eth0 and eth1 on cpu0 and cpu1, leaving other cores for Solarflare cards.

found that tg3 is default to rss max to 5.  Still don't know what's the right parameter, if there's one, to disable it.